# rails count of records for multiple tables on every page of app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, count

I'm trying to add a count to each link on a nav bar. Each link on the nav bar goes to different models.

I want to avoid having to query and count records of multiple models every time a visitor navigates to another page.

How do I cache this information?
`counter_cache` seems to be only for associations. These are standalone models without the need for associations.

Comment: what are we counting exactly, the number of records inside each table ?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: well there's few options, either caching the page, or saving those counts in some new table, or actually do the count, i don't think it would be that expensive, since the primary keys are indexed

Comment: Is it possible lazy-evaluate them the moment the dropdown menu is selected?

Comment: Would you recommend simply doing `Model.all.size`?

Comment: That would costy, because it loads all records from the table, instead run `Model.count` which runs an actual MySQL count query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple `Model.count`, it executes a MySQL count query, which shouldn't cost much.

Then there's the active record cache, which would cache the result of the query with the query string as a cache key, any following requests would hit the cache and it wouldn't even execute the query again, it would be returned directly from the query cache, so I don't think it would be expensive at all.

**EDIT**:

About `.size`, it's is a method for `enumerable`, like arrays, to use it you need to fetch a result set to calculate it's size, that result set is extra data you don't need, you're just interested in the count, so you should just tell the database to fetch the count, hence the `Model.count`, here's an example from an app I already have:

```
User.count
(0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`

User.all.size
User Load (71.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
```

Notice the difference in the queries, also the difference in the response time, first one is very fast because it's already cached.

About the index, in mysql ( and i think any respectful database ) any primary key should be unique and indexed, because that's the primary identifier of the record, you don't need to specify it in the migration, rails creates the auto increment unique primary key by it self, it's a default that it doesn't even appear in the migration files, to disable the creation of primary key you would need to add an extra option `id: false` which is rarely needed.

Comment: When you say primary keys are indexed, are you referring to the default `id` columns? Those are indexed by default by Rails, correct? You don't need to explicitly index them with a migration?

Comment: What about using `.size`? I've read it was better, but it doesn't seem to work as a class method.

Comment: I'll add to my answer cause it's too long

Comment: Excellent, thorough answers. Thanks a bunch.